# how to test static function of another classs in dropwizard

Tags: java, junit, dropwizard

I have an issue in writing a unit test for a function which has static method of another class.

```
public class ClassA{
private static LoadingCache<String, String> someMap;

public static void init() {
        if (someMap == null) {
            someMap = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .concurrencyLevel(10)
                .maximumSize(10) // Maximum of 10 records can be cached
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() { 
                    @Override
                    public String load(String key) {
                       return "myName";
                    }
                });
        }
    }
public static String getName() {
        try {
            return someMap.get("key");
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error {}", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
}
```

Trying to test the following class and it's method:

```
public class ClassB{
public String method(){
final String name = ClassA.getName();
return "Hello: " + name;
}

}
```

1. I am calling ClassA.init() at the start of the service in dropwizard framework. So, I think `someMap` gets initialized that way and all resources can directly use `ClassA.getName()`.

But, when I try to test this, I am getting NPE because `someMap` is not initialized.
How can I simply do:

```
when(ClassB.getName()).thenReturn("myName");
```

Based on the comments:

I added the following to the POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

// test function looks as follows:

```
    @Test
      public void test(){
        mockStatic(ClassA.class);
        when(ClassA.getName()).thenReturn("myName");
// do the rest
      }
```

It works!

Comment: Typically I try to avoid testing/mocking static methods, but if necessary you'll need another library like PowerMock

Comment: @dbrewster cannot make it work for JDK 9 or higher. it is an open issue.

Comment: @dbrewster updated. Even powermock is not easy to use. taking forever

Comment: nvm, I solved it. thanks